# Deleting hdf5 dataset using h5py

Tags: python, dataset, hdf5, h5py

Is there any way to remove a dataset from an hdf5 file, preferably using h5py? Or alternatively, is it possible to overwrite a dataset while keeping the other datasets intact?

To my understanding, h5py can read/write hdf5 files in 5 modes

```
f = h5py.File("filename.hdf5",'mode')
```

where mode can be `r`for read, `r+` for read-write, `a` for read-write but creates a new file if it doesn't exist, `w` for write/overwrite, and  `w-` which is same as `w` but fails if file already exists. I have tried all but none seem to work.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: `del h5py_file[dataset_address]`

Comment: Or..., you can create a new HDF5 file and copy what you need from the old one.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Yes, this can be done.

```
with h5py.File(input,  "a") as f:
    del f[datasetname]
```

You will need to have the file open in a writeable mode, for example append (as above) or write.

*As noted by @seppo-enarvi in the comments the purpose of the previously recommended* `f.__delitem__(datasetname)` *function is to implement the* `del` *operator, so that one can delete a dataset using* `del f[datasetname]`

Comment: The purpose of `__delitem__` function is to implement the `del` operator, so that one can delete a dataset using `del f[datasetname]`.

Comment: @SeppoEnarvi so are you saying that the syntax should be `with h5py.File(input, "a") as f: del f[datasetname]` instead of what is written above?

Comment: I would use `del f[datasetname]`, as it is the standard way to delete an object in Python, and that's also what the documentation advises. But they both probably work.

Comment: The file size remains the same after deleting few dataset. I tried deleting half the data of a 6 GB file and its size remains the same ever, could this be solved?

Comment: @Pratheeswaran, you will likely need to repack the file with one of the HDF group's command line utilities, or you can copy the contents to a new file, then replace the existing file with it. I believe because of the tree structure utilized by HDF5 it's not trivial to recover space.

Answer (score 6):

I tried this out and the only way I could actually reduce the size of the file is by copying everything to a new file and just leaving out the dataset I was not interested in:

```
fs = h5py.File('WFA.h5', 'r')
fd = h5py.File('WFA_red.h5', 'w')
for a in fs.attrs:
    fd.attrs[a] = fs.attrs[a]
for d in fs:
    if not 'SFS_TRANSITION' in d: fs.copy(d, fd)
```

Comment: I've suggested an edit based on some assumptions (SFS_TRANSITION is something specific to your work?) to make your answer more general, please roll back if I've misunderstood something

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what has your question to do with the file open modes. For read/write r+ is the way to go.

To my knowledge, removing is not easy/possible, in particular no matter what you do the file size will not shrink.

But overwriting content is no problem

```
f['mydataset'][:] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to make you aware of a development one of my colleagues made and put online in opensource. It's called `h5nav`.  You can download it with pip install (https://pypi.org/project/h5nav/).

```
pip install h5nav

h5nav toto.h5
ls
rm the_group_you_want_to_delete
exit
```

Note that you'll still have to use h5repack to lower the size of your file.

Best,
Jérôme